# A Connection Attempt Failed using the SFTP Client library SSH.NET

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, ftp-client

Created SFTP client code using the SSH.NET library to transfer a text file using the code below:

```
string destinationWithFileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "test/transferredfiles/", DateTime.Now.Ticks + "hello.txt");
SftpClient _sftpClient = new SftpClient("sftp.example.com", 22, "username", "password");
if (!_sftpClient.IsConnected)
{
    _sftpClient.Connect();
    byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\helloworld.txt");
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileContent);
    _sftpClient.UploadFile(stream, destinationWithFileName);
    _sftpClient.Disconnect();
}
```

But getting the below Exception when trying to connect - `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`. Unable to figure out whether the issue is in code or at the server end.

Comment: What sftp client is that? Is it Renci.Ssh.Net? Seems to me to be a remote server/network issue since your code looks otherwise fine (despite the missing `using`/`Dispose`s)

Comment: yes i am using 'Renci.Ssh.Net'. Could you please provide me some insights on the remote server issue that you are referring to?

Comment: Easiest way to check the connection is using a standard client (e.g. WinSCP) for test. If the connect with same parameters (servername, port, user, password) is successful, it is a problem with your code, otherwise the problem is anywhere: Wrong user/password, firewall, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Try the code on a different machine that does not have a firewall with
  FTP restrictions.
- Download an FTP client (Filezilla, WinScp) to see if you get the same
  issue.

In my case, the corporate policy was blocking my local machine from making an FTP  connection. When  I compiled and ran this code on the development server, it connected without the error.